# What is the meaning of this?

Tags: grammar

I have written a classification in my article and the editor after checking said:
'Cite the classifications in tabular format with appropriate table number and caption'.

So, what is the meaning of "cite the classifications in the tabular format".

I know how to cite the classification but what is meant by ' cite in the tabular format'?

Comment: Why don't you ask the editor?

Comment: "Tabular" refers to tabs. You use tabs to create columns. Your editor is asking for a nicely-designed and readable table (columns and rows). Also, you can ask Google to define a word for you if you don't know what it means: https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3A+tabular